# File upload field causing ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, simple-form

Using rails 4, and trying to add a file field to an existing form, using simple_form and paperclip.

Here's the critical part of the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@employee, html: { class: 'form-horizontal requires', multipart: true}, remote: true) do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :avatar %>

<% end %>
```

Everything works ok, unless I actually submit the form with an uploaded file.  Then, I get this:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in EmployeesController#update
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe your answer is [here][1]

Looks like new with rails 4.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258911/rails-4-authenticity-token

Comment: The problem is combining multipart with remote: true. This will force the form submission as HTML rather than JS. Removing the multipart will force it as JS, but then you cannot upload a file. Obviously, this is a bug, and the remotipart gem apparently is a fix.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simplest solution would just be to add `authenticity_token: true` to your form. 
Like this:

```
<%= form_for @employee, html: { class: 'form-horizontal requires'}, multipart: true, remote: true, authenticity_token: true  do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :avatar %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: adding `authenticity_token: true` worked like a charm :-)

Comment: be warned that `remote: true` option will be ignored and the form is submitted as  `html`. If you want to submit the form as `js` look at [William](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21029501/1079609) answer.

Answer (score 20):

I was with the same problem. `<%= token_tag form_authenticity_token %>` didn't work for me.

Install `gem remotipart` solved my problem. [**remotipart**](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart)

Comment: This is the actual answer if you are trying to submit a file using remote: true and wanting to respond using a js.erb file. Install the remotipart gem (very quick and easy) and it works like a charm.