# Attaching files in form results in InvalidAuthenticityToken error and UnknownFormat error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, carrierwave, authenticity-token

I have something weird going on with a form that's supposed to be submitting image files with the [Carrierwave gem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). Here's the form:

```
<% @post = Post.new %>
<%= form_for @post, url: create_post_path(@post), :html => {multipart: true}, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
  <%= f.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

here's the controller:

```
def create_post
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit({images: []})
end
```

and here's the first error I get:

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in PostsController#create_post
>   ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

This error goes away if I manually set a token by adding this line to the form:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
```

but then I get this error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat in PostsController#create_post
>   ActionController::UnknownFormat

with this line highlighted as problematic:

```
respond_to do |format|
```

**Both errors go away if I remove this line:**

```
<%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
```

Without that line, the form submits normally. I've written many forms using Carrierwave file submission, and I've never run into any of these issues. I also have other forms in the same app with everything the same except the file submission field, and they work fine. What's going on?

**UPDATE**

I think it's deeper than just a authentication problem or a submit-as-JS problem. Manually adding an authentication token fixes one error, but I've written many forms, including AJAX file submission forms, that had no such errors, and I also can't fathom why adding files would affect the authenticity token, so I think something deeper is wrong.

**UPDATE 2**

Turns out it has nothing to do with Carrierwave, or with the created Post having attached images, but rather with the submitted params containing files at all. The errors are still both there when I use a vanilla file upload input:

```
<%= file_field_tag "form_images", multiple: true %>
```

But then if I leave the file upload blank and use a binding.pry in the `create_post` action to set the post's images attribute, everything goes through no problem.

But it gets weirder: even if I manually set the authenticity token, and then have the `create_post` action redirect to a different action, and THEN try to do a `respond_to`, I still get the UnknownFormat error. Again, I do not get this error if the params that get sent to `create_post` do not contain files.

```
<% @post = Post.new %>
<%= form_for @post, url: create_post_path(@post), :html => {multipart: true}, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
  <%= file_field_tag "test_images", multiple: true %>
  <%= f.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def create_post
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  binding.pry #If I leave the file input blank but then set the @post.images here, I get no errors whatsoever.
  @post.save
  redirect_to continue_path(@post.id)
end

def continue
  @post = Post.find(params[:post])
  respond_to do |format| #If I set the authenticity token manually, I still get the UnknownFormat error on this line.
    format.js
  end
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit({images: []})
end
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `authenticity_token: true` to the form. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596450/file-upload-field-causing-actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken-exception). I had the same issue. but this answer helped me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File upload field causing ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596450/file-upload-field-causing-actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken-exception)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to submit as js, then I was able to solve this using the following gem.

`gem remotipart`

[remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart)

Comment: I think there's a deeper problem than js though, because I tried using a `redirect_to` instead of a `respond_to`, and I still got the authentication error.

Comment: Can you change `<%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>` to `<%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true, name: 'images[]' %>`

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately the errors are still there.