# Ruby On Rails form token kick user after code is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

After we update our RoR application and user has opened form and submits his form after code is updated our RoR application says Invalid Authenticity Token and than logs out user who submitted the form.

Is there any way how to solve this and update our code without logging out our users when they have submitted form after code is updated?

Comment: This problem was discussed [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258911/rails-4-authenticity-token

I hope it helps.

Comment: It sounds like you're wiping out user sessions when you restart.