# Rails 5 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails application which I am planning to upgrade to rails 5. I am using devise(v4.2.0) along with rails(v5.0.0). As suggested in devise README.md file, I tried moving the protect_from_forgery above the before_filter but still when I am trying to login or update my bug I get an error `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`

My `Application Controller` is

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
   end

end
```

And my other `BugController` is

```
class BugsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery prepend: true, with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_bug, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

    def update
      respond_to do |format|
      if @bug.update(bug_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @bug, notice: 'Bug was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @bug }
     else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @bug.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
     end
   end

private
def bug_params
  params.require(:bug).permit(:product, :component, :title, :description, :status_id, :created_by_id, :assigned_to_id)
end


end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Note**: While this answer has the desired effect, it does so by reducing overall security. The below answer by Alon is more correct and maintains the security of the site.

```
class BugsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
protect_from_forgery prepend: true, with: :exception
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :set_bug, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
end
```

Like This

Comment: I tried putting `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` in bugs controller but still does not work.

Comment: In `Bugs controller`   `protect_from_forgery prepend: true, with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_bug, only: [:show, :edit, :update]`

Comment: Tried with your provided answer, but I am still getting error `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in BugsController#update
`

Comment: put that on application controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117114/discussion-between-hsd-and-boltz0r).

Comment: It is better to use skip_before_action instead of skip_before_filter...

Comment: I did this and it worked, but in light of the below reply I believe this is a poor answer.

Comment: Prefer the answer below from @alon-burg

Answer (score 81):

As indicated in [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/4033/files) notes for Rails 5

> For Rails 5, note that `protect_from_forgery` is no longer prepended
>   to the `before_action` chain, so if you have set `authenticate_user`
>   before `protect_from_forgery`, your request will result in "Can't
>   verify CSRF token authenticity." To resolve this, either change the
>   order in which you call them, or use `protect_from_forgery prepend:
>   true`.

Comment: This seems like a way better option than skipping the verification of the authenticity token!!

Comment: This should be the chosen answer

Comment: This solution helped and in my case too. I have AWS CloudFront with SSL and Route53 and I was have similar issue: I was sending post request to rails app (feedback form without login) and via http all works fine without CSRF token, but over SSL pitost wasn't worked. I was need to add custom origin header at cloudfront to fix issue `Origin header didn't match request.base_url`, then I was have issue `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` and when I added token to request and added header `'X-CSRF-Token': authenticity_token` I was have issue `InvalidAuthenticityToken` and this solution helped me

Comment: Thank you! It's straightforward.

Comment: Would this also apply to rails 6 ?

Answer (score 5):

I recently hit this in a fairly large way and I found that my error was my application's domain name had recently changed but I forgot to update session_store.rb.  That may not be everyone's issue but it will report this as a CSRF error.  So please check out config/session_store.rb

Comment: fyi it is config/initializers/session_store.rb I believe

Answer (score 1):

I have used something like this and it works for me.

```
class WelcomeController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :authenticate_model!
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This decision helped me. I took the decision [from here] [1]. just as for me, the unfortunate name of that topic, using the keywords of error I didn’t get there, so I’ll give in this thread, because here is the exact name of the error.
in my case, I "added" the following line to the `application_controller.rb` file:

```
protect_from_forgery with:: null_session
```

there is a solution where it says "REPLACE" line `protect_from_forgery with:: exception` , if it exists, to the one I quoted above

[1]: [Rails 4 Authenticity Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258911/rails-4-authenticity-token)