# Devise in Rails doesn't work with HTTPs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, https, devise

After I press the button to "sign in" on https://myapp.com/users/sign_in, the following error appears:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#create
```

regardless of the existing user's credentials.

If I press the button to sign in on http://myapp.com/users/sign_in, the user signs in and the application seems to work smoothly, except the user cannot create posts under HTTPs too.

I want to make devise authentication work under SSL.

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users
```

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :registerable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

1. I have the `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in the head
2. I cleared the cookies in browsers
3. I tried `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` instead of `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in app/controllers/application_controller.rb
4. I tried to put `<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>` in the `form_for` for new session
5. I tried `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }` in root
6. I tried to add

   ```
   config.to_prepare { Devise::SessionsController.force_ssl }
   config.to_prepare { Devise::RegistrationsController.force_ssl }
   config.to_prepare { Devise::PasswordsController.force_ssl }
   ```

   in config/environments/production.rb

Comment: may be this will resolve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331496/rails-5-actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken-error

Comment: @bunty, well, it didn't

Comment: this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-SSL-(HTTPS)

Answer (score 0):

put one line in sessions_controller

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

and in routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers:
                  {
                    sessions: 'users/sessions',
                  }
```

because its not require authentication_token when user login

Comment: Mayur, where is sessions_controller?

Comment: I will try to create a sessions_controller.rb in controllers/users/sessions folder

Comment: Error: uninitialized constant Users::SessionsController

It seems I need more expanded explanations from you.

Comment: sessions_controller is generated by devise itself  app/controllers/users/sessios_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

There is the workaround of disabling CSRF protection for the sign_in action in the application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  ....
end
```

Set it as:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery  with: :exception
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, if: -> { controller_name == 'sessions' && action_name == 'create' }
  ...
end
```